# PHP files are downloaded by browser instead of processed by local dev server (MAMP)

Tags: php, apache, macos, configuration, mamp

Everything was going great until I added `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php` to the .htaccess file in my local server's document root (which I change frequently depending on the site I'm working with). Since I did that when I visit http://localhost:8888 my browser just downloads the index.php and it's not processed at all, just the raw code. Now **I removed that line from the .htaccess file but I'm still having this problem**.

I've found that if I add an alternative entry to my hosts file for 127.0.0.1 the new entry behaves like 'localhost' used to. But if I add the line above to my .htaccess it knocks out that new host as well. I've tried reinstalling [MAMP](http://mamp.info) and clearing its caches and all the temporary files I could find. I surfed through Apache's httpd.conf file all to no avail.

So, to be clear: http://localhost:8888 is experiencing the above problem. If I add a new entry to my hosts file for 127.0.0.1, say 'goomba' and the above line is not in the root .htaccess (and has never been for that host/alias/whatever) then I can access http://goomba:8888 just fine. But if I do add that line to the .htaccess then I have to add yet another entry to my hosts file to get around it *even if I remove that line from the the .htaccess file*.

I'm fine with using a different 127.0.0.1 alias (host? what is that called?) but it's bugging me that this is still broken.

Just to be clear, I'm on Mac OS Leopard (but I'm not using the built in Apache setup, but MAMP).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are applying a mimetype where a handler should be (see [documentation on handlers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/handler.html))

Try this instead:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

EDIT: 
As you have indicated caching modules are loaded, you could read up on [caching](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html) and [htcacheclean](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htcacheclean.html) (to clear the disk cache). You can also temporarily use the [CacheDisable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html#cachedisable) directive. One other thing that you could also try is to rename the file that you have requested (e.g. index.php -> index.bak), request the file again in the browser (should now 404), then revert and try again.

Comment: I've tried that (and again, just now) to no avail. My httpd.conf already has that line (minus the 5), anyways. My problem is that, despite the problematic line mentioned in my question being removed, I'm still having problems. It's like the server has cached the .htaccess file only for `localhost`, not for other hosts that point to 127.0.0.1. Please added emphasis to my question for clarification. Thank you, anyways!

Comment: Does the server have any cache modules loaded? Yes, the "5" was left in by accident

Comment: It does: file_cache_module, cache_module, disk_cache_module, and mem_cache_module. How could I clear these caches? Would any of these cause this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Simply renaming the file, trying to access it by the old name, and then renaming it again as you described worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

I've had a similar issue a couple times and renaming the file did not work for me. With OS X Lion I found the right configuration is this:

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The magic that made it work for me is the `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` part.

Of course edit the `<IfModule php5_module>` to your php version.

Comment: This was the case on OSX Mountain Lion as well.

Comment: where should this be placed?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: Late to the party, but place that in `/etc/apache2/other/php5.conf` and make sure that apache's main configuration (in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`) has an uncommented line (near the bottom) that reads: `Include /etc/apache2/other/*.conf`.

Comment: This worked for me as well macOS Sierra. The odd thing is, I encountered this problem when switching from Mamp 3.5 to Mamp 4. By adding SetHandler application/x-httpd-php things started to work again.

Comment: I have no idea why this worked, but after 4+ hours and 50+ google searches it worked! NOTE: I had to change php5_module to php7_module because I'm on php7.3

Answer (score 4):

Just note, make sure you don't have a htaccess file from your live environment accidentally downloaded with other files. Additionally, make sure you match your PHP version when editing htaccess. Wrong version cause same issue-wrong settings.

Here is an example for running PHP7:

> application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml

I hope this info can help - it happened to me 8 years after ticket is created :)

Comment: I had a similar issue - htdocs/.htaccess contained the line `AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php` and it was failing silently. Work around was to remove the line.

Answer (score 4):

If someone has again this kind of issue, do something most important firstly. I mean, use private navigation (without cache).
I wasted my time because of this.

GLHF

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want `application/x-httpd-php5` instead of `application/x-httpd-php5s`? (Note the lack of an `s` at the end.)

Comment: I tried that to no avail. Before it was working just fine without anything in the .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

in my case deleting or comment out "AddHandler php56-cgi .php" in my root's involved htacces files solved it

Best

Answer (score 1):

For the same issue, i removed the '5' AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html

its working fine! try

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was because inside this folder you have .htaccess file hidden with some custom code, for me was because I copy from my running website server. Try to rename the file and you will see your project. Then customise the file in your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your apache server is running. Start->Run->cmd and then execute command:

netstat -abn

Lookup the result for line like this:

TCP 0.0.0.0:8888 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 600 [apache.exe]

If you cant find anything listening on port 8888 ( no 0.0.0.0:8888 line) then your apache is failing to start. To find out why it cant start you should find apache log directory and examine the error.log (may be you have updated your php resently?). If you find 0.0.0.0:80 listening line but some other software is listening there (do you have IIS running?) then you should remove / reconfigure that softure to free port 80. If you have apache listening on port 80 but still cant open your site and you cant figure out what is causing the problem via examining apache log files then it my be database problem. Check if your mysql is running and listening using same command but you should be looking for

TCP 0.0.0.0:3306 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING [mysqld-nt.exe]

If you cant find such line then your mysql server is not running - check mysql log files for errors. If both servers are running and you cant get any output in your browser then check your firewall and antivirus - they may block your requests. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: A few things: I'm on Mac OS Leopard; the Apache server is working for new entries to my hosts file. Please see the updates to my post for more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a very similar issue. All of my php files were downloading when I tried to test if php and apache were working together. It turns out they weren't working together.

I had to uninstall php, I would recomend the same course of action and then reinstalling php just using the zip file download on php.net, instead of installing it with MAMP. I think my problem was that I had used the php installer. I do not recomend using that.

This website helped me a lot, I was having an issue with apache not starting and while that is not your issue, this website solved both the apache not starting and the downloading of php files issue and even though you are on a mac it may help you as well http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/185771-problem-starting-apache-2214-after-installing-php-5212

Hope everything works! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the comment

```
<IfDefine PHP>
   LoadModule php_module        modules/libphp.so
</IfDefine>
```

in etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf

Answer (score 0):

In my case after cloning a repo and trying to set the project up i hade to run  `composer update` to install the all dependencies and then it open the page instead of downloading the file