# Configure virtualhost root

Tags: php, apache, symfony, configuration, virtualhost

I need to configure my virtualhost , I have a symfony installation in /home/sfproduction/www/prod/public/
I need to change my root  in order to point to my folder /public/

I have check symfony doc but I don't understand .
How can I proceed ?

My current virtualhost setting is that but It doesn't work(display Bad Gateway):

----(I have put .after < in order to display on the forum)---

```
<./VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName sfproduction.alwaysdata.net

  DocumentRoot "/home/sfproduction/www/prod/public/web"

  DirectoryIndex index.php

Alias /  /home/sfproduction/www/prod/public/

  <Directory /sfproduction/www/prod/public>

   AllowOverride All

   Allow from All

  </Directory>

<*/VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: @Filo It's doesn't work : check my website [link](http://sfproduction.alwaysdata.net)

Answer (score 0):

referring to the cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sfproduction.alwaysdata.net

  DocumentRoot /home/sfproduction/www/prod/public/web        
  <Directory /home/sfproduction/www/prod/public/web>
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**Updated after the comments:**

The original question is **solved**, infact now your url points to your symfony app.php

Now your php paged are downloaded insted of been seen.
This problem can be due to a misconfiguration of Apache;

see those related question to understand how to solve:
[PHP files are downloaded by browser instead of processed by local dev server (MAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316610/php-files-are-downloaded-by-browser-instead-of-processed-by-local-dev-server-ma)

https://serverfault.com/questions/215455/what-causes-php-pages-to-consistently-download-instead-of-running-normally