# Live Hosting MySQL with PHP won't connect to my AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

After I struggling with some errors, later I've succeeded create PHP connector with my live hosting mysql, but unfortunately my AngularJS failed to connect. I create php with json format called json.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$conn = new mysqli("domain","user","pass","db_name");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT UID, Name, City, Country FROM records");
$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
$outp .= '{"UID":"'  . $rs["UID"] . '",';
$outp .= '{"Name":"'  . $rs["Name"] . '",';
 $outp .= '"City":"'   . $rs["City"]        . '",';
$outp .= '"Country":"'. $rs["Country"]     . '"}';
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();
echo($outp);
?>
```

my controller

```
var testAppApp = angular.module('testAppApp', []);
testAppApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('json.php')
        .then(function(takeprocess) {
            $scope.customers = takeprocess.data.records;
        });
});
```

My index.html

```
<html ng-app="testAppApp">
<head>
..................
..................
</head>
<div ng-controller="SimpleController">
Search <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name" />
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name">{{cust.UID}} -   
{{cust.Name}} - {{cust.City}} - {{cust.Country}}</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/SimpleController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, when I run json.php in MAMP (for testing) using Apache Server the data show like below

```
{"records":[{"UID":"1",{"Name":"Konohamaru","City":"Leaf Village","Country":"Konoha District"},{"UID":"2", {"Name":"Gaara","City":"Sand Village","Country":"Sand Desert Union"}]}
```

This mean, I have no issue with live hosting sql server, authentication, or any. This is works well. But strangely enough when I access the php file directly with "localhost:9000/json.php" the code can't show anything, instead the browser downloading my script.

NOTE :
My console not show error(s) notification too, but still when I run "Grunt Server" and take the process to open localhost:9000 my App didn't show any dummy data from my live host DB. But when I testing with data.json, for the purpose if my code actually works, voila the good thing happen, my data showing. I still confuse, where I was wrong in this process, please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316610/php-files-are-downloaded-by-browser-instead-of-processed-by-local-dev-server-ma

Comment: @Yolo, not yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I made it self finally. First, I don't know it proxy issue or what. But since I know grunt can't execute PHP file (before modified), later I search where the wrong my project.

First, I've indicated Grunt Server can't execute PHP, so I must modify gruntfile.js based on this article ["Use PHP with your Yeoman dev server"](https://coderwall.com/p/bal2_a/use-php-with-your-yeoman-dev-server) but honestly, there is no softly step by step how and where you can put your code. In shortcut, here I put my code in Gruntfile.js (near top)

```
// Generated on 2017-03-13 using generator-angular 0.16.0
'use strict';
var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-       
livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet;
var gateway = require('gateway');
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};
```

And here....

```
 livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          lrSnippet,
          gateway(__dirname + '/app', {
          '.php': 'php-cgi'}),
          mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
          mountFolder(connect, 'app'),
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
```

In specific section, I add below return [ .....

```
lrSnippet,
          gateway(__dirname + '/app', {
          '.php': 'php-cgi'}),
          mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
          mountFolder(connect, 'app'),
```

After that, I edit my json.php like below

```
<?php
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("hosting","username","pass","db_name") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select * from records";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($emparray);

//write to json file
//$fp = fopen('data.json', 'w');
//fwrite($fp, json_encode($emparray));
//fclose($fp);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

And edit my controller little bit

```
var testAppApp = angular.module('testAppApp', []);
testAppApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('json.php')
        .then(function(takeprocess) {
            $scope.customers = takeprocess.data;
        });
});
```

Later, I start "Grunt Build" and try "Grunt Server". My App show in localhost:9000 but still blank, but when I change my Wifi. My App works like charm, I can connecting my Live hosting MySQL with my local Grunt.

But, it seems I have complicated thing, My Grunt not supporting to read PHP before, and I suspect my network not stable or have proxy issue, I don't know. But when I try again, clean my project with default setting (without gateway setting in Gruntfile.js). My app have error(s) again.

I hope this help to everyone who have same experience with me.

NOTE : There are several dependencies you must done, Install gateway in your project not global

```
npm install gateway
```

If you notice here...

```
var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet;
```

variable LrSnippet need dependencies grunt-contrib-
livereload, just do

```
npm install grunt-contrib-livereload
```

sudo if needed