# PHP page start downloading instead ot showing content

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I am trying to make working `laravel 5.4` on shared hosting. I am using below code of `.htaccess` file, but it start downloading files instead of showing content. below is my `.htaccess` code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
# Use PHP70 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php70/lib
</IfModule>
```

I don't know, where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-but-the-code-shows-in-the-browser-source-code

Answer (score 1):

Probably dublicated

[Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)

[PHP files are downloaded by browser instead of processed by local dev server (MAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316610/php-files-are-downloaded-by-browser-instead-of-processed-by-local-dev-server-ma)

Make sure it's Apache and not Nginx

If it's nginx the answer may be this

[Nginx serves .php files as downloads, instead of executing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in your .htaccess file

Here is mine .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mime_module>
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml 
</IfModule>
```

Remove the last "IfModule - mime_module" part and restart your wamp or xampp server